# Can't pass data to parent component / React UseState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have mapped an array of objects which returns a toggle component for each object. I wanna be able to update the objects in the array based on the toggle state but I can't find a way to **pass the toggle state (which is handled in the child component) of a specific object.**

Here is the code of the parent component (i deleted a bit of code for better readability):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { RadioGroup } from "@headlessui/react";
import Toggle from "./Toggle";

const frameVariants= [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "Caisse américaine",
    description: "Aucun aperçu disponible pour le moment",
    state: true,
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Photo encadrée",
    description: "Aucun aperçu disponible pour le moment",
    state: true,
  }
];

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function TableToggle(props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(frameVariants[0]);
  const [details, showDetails] = useState(true);


  return (
    <RadioGroup defaultValue={props.defaultValue} onChange={props.onChange}>
      <RadioGroup.Label className="sr-only">Privacy setting</RadioGroup.Label>
      <div className="bg-gray-50 shadow-inner rounded-md -space-y-px">
        {frameVariants.map((variant, variantIdx) => (
          <div key={variant.key}>
            <RadioGroup.Option
              key={variant.key}
              value={variant.name}>
                <>
                  <span
                    className=""
                    aria-hidden=""
                  >
                    <Toggle id={variant.key} variant={variant}/>
                  </span>
                 
                </>
            </RadioGroup.Option>
          </div>
      </div>
    </RadioGroup>
  );
}
```

And here is the code of the child component :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Switch } from "@headlessui/react";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function Toggle(props) {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(props.variant);

  const handleToggleState = () => {
    setEnabled((val) => !val)};

  return (
    <Switch
      key={props.id}
      checked={enabled}
      onChange={handleToggleState}
      
      className={classNames(
        enabled ? "bg-indigo-600" : "bg-gray-200",
        "relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
      )}
    >
      <span className="sr-only">Use setting</span>
      <span
        aria-hidden="true"
        className={classNames(
          enabled ? "translate-x-5" : "translate-x-0",
          "pointer-events-none inline-block h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200"
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not working because you have not passed the data from parent component to child, In your case look at this `<Toggle id={variant.key}/>` . You are only passing id from here but in `Toggle` component you are trying to access `props.frameVariants`. which is not being passed from the parent.  See here `const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(props.frameVariants);`

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not yet solving my issue. I've done what you said. Now else what should I do ? How can I make it so that setEnabled updates the object in the parent component? @VishalKumar

Comment: Please update the question(codes) what you have tried.

Comment: Just did. @VishalKumar

Answer (score 0):

You must give a boolean value to the "enabled" variable in the Toggle component.

You need to change it like this:

```
const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(props.variant.state);
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: Although console.log(props.variant.state) inside the handleToggleState function does return a value true/false

Comment: You get this error cause "variant" is not an object. You pass it wrongly to the child component.  Make sure that you pass it correctly. And I think you do not need to pass the object to the child component. It is enough to pass the "state" property of the object.

Comment: Change it in the parent component like: <Toggle id={variant.key} variant={variant.state}/> and like i said before, make sure that the variant is the object that you want to pass the child component

Comment: And do not forget to change this: const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(props.variant);

Comment: Thank you for your help but it doesn't work. It's not changing the object, the state of the variant remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method inside your TableToggle component

```
const updateFrameVariants = (id, state) => {
  frameVariants.find(fv => fv.id == id).state = state;
}
```

Pass that into your Toggle component

```
<Toggle id={variant.key} updateFrameVariants={updateFrameVariants} variant={variant}/>
```

Then call it inside your Toggle component

```
useEffect(() => {
   props.updateFrameVariants(props.id, enabled)
}, [enabled])
```

That will modify your frameVariants object in your parent component whenever you change a state in your child component

Comment: Thank you for your help Ahmet but i'm facing some issues with your solution. Where should I put useEffect ? I tried adding it inside of handleToggleState but I get an error "Invalid hook call". I also tried adding it after onChange but I get another error "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'state')"

Comment: After you set enabled inside Toggle component, you need a way to notify parent component. So what comes into my mind is to use a method for this purpose. I call that method using useEffect inside Toggle component. whenever you enabled state changes.